# How to install RabbitVCS in Ubuntu 11.10 Ocelot?

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, rabbitvcs

I tried to install RabbitVCS on my machine following this [guide](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu) but failed.

I'm stuck since the guide is officially from RabbitVCS. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the PPAs are not available (going by the 404 and a cursory glance [over here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/)). I'd wait a bit till the PPAs are available.

Answer (score 1):

First, download the tarball from here http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/downloads/detail?name=rabbitvcs-0.15.0.5.tar.bz2&can=2&q=

Then, you'll need to extract it somewhere (I put it on the desktop)

Next step, open a terminal and:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rabbitvcs-0.15.0.5/
```

Then run the following command:

```
sudo python setup.py install --install-layout=deb
```

Next, run the following command:

```
sudo cp ./clients/nautilus-3.0/RabbitVCS.py /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions
```

then run:

```
nautilus -q
```

then:

```
pgrep -f service.py | xargs kill
```

then:

```
nohup nautilus > /dev/null &
```

Good luck ;P